# How to make REST Callouts from Visual Workflow?

Tags: rest-api, callout, flow, visual-workflow, invocable-method

We have a requirement where we need to accept some inputs (couple of text inputs) from user and pass this input to a REST Service which will return search results(List of a custom class) based on the search criteria input passed.

I found lot of examples which use Process Plugin and very few which use Invocable Method.
What are the pros and cons of both when used in such scenario ?

Comment: This release notes might be worth a read:  http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_apex.htm. Since you mentioned REST service, Invocable method seems to be an ideal choice.

Comment: I have same requirement, how to make callouts with flow, can some one advise with example.